# How can I transfer some data between ActionMethods without using TempData or the Db

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a controller action which returns a password protected zip file to the user when the click a link. The password is generated randomly.

If the download is successful, I'd like to then call another action method on the controller to get the password and display it on the screen. I'd be happy to do it all in one request but it doesn't feel possibly in a non horrible way.

I'm using this library to download the file [jquery download library](http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/)

I can't use tempdata or session state and hitting the database feels a little bit like using a hammer to crack a nut. I've thought about storing it in the response or a cookie but that feels a bit wrong too.

Comment: I know only these to persist data. Client Side `cookie/url/hiddenfield` Server Side `Session/TempData/Application/DB`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URL or hidden field should do (that is, they are both user-stored either as part of POST or GET request).
The question is, how can you return the password to the client and start the download at the same time. If there's no server storage you can't do it, since they are separate HTTP requests (unless you use cookie). I think this is the best way to do it:

1. Open your download page, and generate the password at that time,
   so you can put it in hidden field (for successCallback of jquery
   download library)
2. When calling your server to download the file,
   pass the password as get or post to the download URL, and use this
   password to compress
3. Once download finishes, you know what the
   password was, so you can redirect to another page and show it.
   Actually, since you already have it on the page, you can show it
   right after download using javascript. Or maybe you can just show
   the password right away, while download is still happening.

So, this is probably reversal of your architecture. And possibly this is not acceptable (you may want to generate secure passwords and guarantee users don't mess with them - that's possible if you pass the password in the download request). But that's the only way without server or cookie storage.

Answer (score 0):

use 
        return RedirectToAction("Action", new { id = 99 });